# Can I submerge a pneumatic cylinder in oil?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, pneumatic

I am looking for a linear pneumatic cylinder to raise and lower a fixed object. Everything will be submerged in oil (for electrical purposes). I am new to engineering and pneumatics in particular, and I don't know if I can completely submerge the cylinder without damaging it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a double-acting cylinder then possibly fine, BUT you will need to check the seals are not going to be damaged by the oil and make sure that the pressure inside the cylinder, on both sides of the piston, is greater than the oil pressure so oil is less likely to make its way past the seals.

A single acting cylinder needs to be able to fill or expel air on the low pressure side of the piston which will be an issue when submerged.